# Maximum sum of non adjacent elements in a 2D array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to look for an algorithm that will help me find the maximum sum of non adjacent elements in a 2D array.

For 1D arrays, I've found helpful solutions from:
1) http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-sum-such-that-no-two-elements-are-adjacent/
2) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UtGtF6nc35g

For example in a 1D array: {3, 2, 6, 2, 10}
I will get a maximum sum of 19, because 3, 6 and 10 are non adjacent.

However, I'm unable to find one that can help me with a 2D array. How can i find the maximum sum of integers in this array without horizontal or vertical adjacent elements? Diagonally adjacent elements are allowed.

For example:

```
[3, 2, 6, 2, 10]
[1, 5, 2, 5, 1]
[5, 1, 7, 2, 9]
[3, 9, 1, 8, 2]
```

Is there an existing algorithm to solve this problem? Or would it be another method to solve this problem if I used another data structure instead of a 2D array?

Comment: Do you have four-way adjacency or eight-way?

Comment: Sorry for not specifying, horizontal and vertical is not allowed, but diagonal adjacency is allow.

Comment: Is this about "how" or "how with the best possible time complexity"? Do you need the maximum or is an approximation sufficient? What size of 2D arrays are we talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Problem can be stated as [maximum-weight independent set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)) or [mixed integer linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) problem.

To convert it to maximum-weight independent set, create graph where vertices are elements and edges are adjacency.

I am not expert on integer programming. There is similar (even more complicated) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38963156/optimal-filling-of-grid-figure-with-squares) where sascha demonstrated how to transform problem to MIP, and power of solvers.