# A variant of the 2D knapsack or square packing

Tags: r, algorithm, optimization, mathematical-optimization, combinatorics

I am dealing with an optimisation issue, which I classified as a combinatorial problem. Now, I know this is a 2D variant of the knapsack problem, but please bear with me:

If I have an area that is modeled as a grid comprised of equal size cells, how to place a certain number of square objects of different sizes, on this  grid area, if every object has its cost and its benefit and the goal is to have an arrangement of the objects that has the maximum Benefit/Cost ratio:

- Object 1: 1x1 square, cost = 800, value= 2478336
- Object 2: 2x2 square    cost= 2000 value = 7565257
- Object 3: 3x3 square cost= 3150 value=    14363679

The object 3 has the best value/cost ratio, so the approach would be a greedy one I guess, to first place as much of the bigger squares as possible, but still there are many optimal solutions depending on the size of the area.

Also, the square objects cannot overlap.
I am using R for this, and the package adagio has algorithms for the single and multiple knapsack, but not for a 2D knapsack problem. Because I am very new in optimization and programming, I am not sure if there is way of solving this problem with R, can someone please help?
Thanks!

Comment: Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38963156/optimal-filling-of-grid-figure-with-squares).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm not an expert in R and adagio. Secondly, I think that your problem is not exactly 2d knapsack, it looks like a variant of [packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems), so it requires a different approach.

So, first, check this awesome list of [R optimization packages](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html), especially the following sections:

1. Specific Applications in Optimization (for example, tabu search could be useful for you)
2. Mathematical Programming Solvers/Interfaces to Open Source Optimizers ([lpsolve](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/) definitely could solve your task)
3. Global and Stochastic Optimization (some of this packages could be used to solve your task)

In case if you're not tied to *R*, consider [Minizinc](http://www.minizinc.org/) as a solver. It's very easy to install/use and it's pretty efficient in terms of memory/time consumption. Moreover, there is a bunch of great examples how to use it.

Comment: Yes, you might be right that it is not a knapsack problem. Although the knapsack is described as a variant of the packing problem, it does not take into account the geometry, so would not make sense maybe in this case. I have already considered the variant of packing squares in a square problem, and should probably go in that direction. Thank you!

Comment: @Dragana My point is that it's unlikely that you can reuse something from adagio - packing problem is more general. :)

Comment: Yes I agree definitely. I am already familiar with the Cran repository of optimization packages, I guess my problem is in the formulation itself, due to not having sufficient knowledge for solving this kind of problems..

Comment: @Dragana Try Minizinc, it's very simple. You'll get some experience and understanding how it works and what to do, then switch to a R package.